# How do I find the area in a valley inside my plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, integral

I have a plot of Heat flow vs Temperature. I am pretty new so I may be missing something obvious, but I wanted to find the area of a valley in my plot. I plotted my values given by DSC, and the lines are the area I wanted to find. I have been trying to take an integral of this range but no sucess.

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(Ts, abs(HF),'k')
plt.plot([650,765],[153,153], 'r')
plt.plot([665,725],[145,145])
plt.grid(color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5)
plt.title('Heat Flow vs Temperature')
plt.xlabel('Temperature (C)')
plt.ylabel('Heat Flow (mW)')
plt.show()

fx=[Ts, abs(HF)]
integral = np.trapz(abs(HF)[650:765])
print(integral)
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are on the right track, but some details are missing. What is the value of `integral`? What is the scale of the `y` axis on your plot?

Comment: Supposing the x-axis goes in steps of one, the area would be the area of a rectangle from 0 to the red line minus the integral. So, `(765-650)*153-integral`